How to automatically add query conditions for all find* or queryBuilder in typeorm?
I am implementing a multi-tenant application based on table column tenantId.
@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryColumn()
  id!: string

  // other column ...

  @Column()
  tenantId!: string
}

And for insert, i can automatically set the tenantId value upon insertion by implementing a subscriber.
@EventSubscriber()
export class TenantSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {
  async beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>) {
    for await (const item of event.metadata.primaryColumns) {
      if (event.entity['tenantId'] === undefined) {
        event.entity['tenantId'] = getCurrentTenantId()
      }
    }
    return event
  }
}

I would like to ask how to automatically add the tenant ID condition when performing queries, updates, and deletions as well.
This way, I won't have to write a bunch of repetitive code.

Subscribers are primarily used to log query execution. A request intercepted by a subscriber cannot be modified. More precisely, its text can be changed, but the request that was before the adjustment will be executed.
In your situation, you can use custom repositories

Custom repositories need to code andWhere("user.tenantId = :tenantId", { tenantId }) everywhere.
